# Spark form not showing up in flashbuilder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flashbuilder4, flex-spark

I am going through the flex in a week training and I'm trying to use the  Spark form in Flashbuilder 4, but it does not appear in the components windows. When I drag a form from there it is an mx form control.

The project is set to use the 4.5 sdk and I can even create the  tag in the code view, but when I do that is doesn't show up in the designer...

How can I get the spark form control to either show up in the designer when created in the code view, or get the control to show up in the components window so I can drag it in?

Comment: Which version of flash builder are you using?

Comment: Like the title and post say. Version 4

Comment: If you can, use FlashBuilder 4.5 (60-day free trial). Or better yet: don't use the design view.

Answer (score 1):

Hence the question whether you were using Flash Builder 4 or Flash Builder 4.5

I have tested this in Flash Builder 4.5 and it works without any problem. And yes I really had to test this because I haven't used design mode since well.. forever :P

You should use Flash Builder 4.5 if you really need to use the design view.

The upgrade comes at a very reasonable price too.

Cheers

Comment: I'd like to add that using design view is *not* recommended if you want to create good code.  It's very easy to just look at the code and decipher how it's being laid it.  If that's not enough, just run the app.